# publish codecoverage for scala unit test results in Azure devops

Tags: azure, scala, azure-devops, sbt, code-coverage

```
script: |
      cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/framework/project1-scala/project1-scala && sbt clean
      echo "sbt Clean"
    displayName: 'Running $ sbt clean'
  - script: |
      cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/framework/project1-scala/project1-scala && sbt update
      echo "sbt update"
    displayName: 'Running $ sbt update'
  - script: |
      cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/framework/project1-scala/project1-scala && sbt compile
      echo "sbt compile"
    displayName: 'Running $ sbt compile'
  - script: |
      cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/framework/project1-scala/project1-scala && sbt clean coverage test
      echo "sbt test & coverage"
    displayName: 'Running $ sbt test & coverage'
  - script: |
      cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/framework/project1-scala/project1-scala  && sbt coverageReport
      echo "sbt coverageReport"      
    displayName: 'Running $ sbt coverageReport'
  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
      summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/scoverage.xml'
      reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/htmlcov
```

'I want to see coverageReport in Azure pipeline UI but it is not showing. Even though I have given scoverage.xml file path correctly.It seems this file not recognizing while generating the coveragrereport.This is scala unit testing with scoverage plugin.  All three files are publishing but I could not be able to see the results in codecoverage tab'

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion on the above query will be helpful. Thank you